# How to upload a file/image through tastypie

Tags: javascript, python, django, file-upload, tastypie

I'm having an issue while developing an api with tastypie.
What I want basically is to know if there is a way to post an image to tastypie within json directly.

In my models right now i'm using an ImageField :

```
  class MyClass(models.Model):
      description = models.TextField()
      user = models.ForeignKey(User)
      photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="image", null=True, blank=True)
```

Then in my api file :

```
    class InquiryResource(ModelResource):
        user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user' ,full=True)
        photo = fields.FileField(attribute = 'photo', null=True, blank = True)

        class Meta :
            queryset = MyClass.objects.all()
            resource_name = "MyClass"
            authorization = Authorization()
```

When i send this a basic json with only user and description it works well.
Then when I go to add informations about my image :

```
    { ... ,
    photo : {
       Content-Type : "image/png",
       file : "base64string", <----- this one contains the file as a long string
       name : "test.png"
    } ...}
```

I get an error message : 'dict' objects has no attribute '_commited'

Is there a "clean way" to upload a file natively with tastypie or should I use Base64FileField?

Thank you

Comment: You need to write a custom `hydrate_photo()` function that takes in your JSON subdocument and populates the FileField - TastyPie doesn't support what you're trying to do out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can just use Base64FileField: https://gist.github.com/jstarcher/ef8d91b8e8d058178f20

Read more about this: https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/issues/42